# How to loop for every value in table AND find average

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to find the average user rating of vendor 2.
My steps are as follows:
1. User 'Jimmy' gives a **rating of 3** to **vendor 2** (ratings are out of 5)
2.TABLE *vendoratings* is updated
[image]
3. *ratingstot.php* then calculates the total sum of **ratings** and **the number of responses** for **ALL** vendors before **updating** TABLE *vendortotalratings* shown below
[image]
4.User 'Jimmy' clicks on 'View average user rating'
5. The values *totalratings* and *totalno* are retrieved and divided in Javascript

```
var average= totalratings/totalno
```

6. totalno is displayed to user Jimmy. END

**Question**
 1. I need help forming the for or while loop in ratingstot.php to calculate both ratings and no. of responses belonging to vendor X before inserting them in *vendortotalratings* table for every vendor.
*ratingstot.php*

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
try{
    //Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "XXXXXXXX_XXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");

    //Unsure how to loop this to make vendor new value every loop
    for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
    $vendor = ??

        //Calculate sum of ratings from table ratings
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT SUM(ratings) FROM ratings WHERE vendorid = '".$vendorid."' ");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $totalratings = $row[0];

        //Calculate no. of responses (by counting no. of rows)
        $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE vendorid = '" . $vendorid."' ");
        $totalno = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //inserting the results into the table
        $query  = " UPDATE vendortotalratings SET ";
        $query .= " totalratings = '". $totalratings ."', totalno='".$totalno."' ";
        $query .= " WHERE vendorid = '". $vendorid ."'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($query);

    }
    echo($outp);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
    echo $json_out; 
}
?>
```

2. I have no idea how to loop this, are there any easier steps to calculate average of ratings for each vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all these complicated things, you can simplify **the required solution** like this:
(Assumption: I'm assuming that *vendorid*, *ratings*, *totalratings* and *totalno* columns are of type `INT`)

- Use the below statement/query to get the *totalratings* and *totalno* corresponding to each *vendorid*.

  ```
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT vendorid, SUM(ratings) as totalratings, COUNT(userid) as totalno FROM vendorratings GROUP BY vendorid");
  ```
- Now loop through the `$result` result set using `while()` loop.

  ```
  while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      ...
  }
  ```
- In each iteration of above `while()` loop, check if the *vendorid* value already exists or not. If it exists, then `UPDATE` the row with new *totalratings* and *totalno*, otherwise `INSERT` a new row comprising of *vendorid*, *totalratings* and *totalno*.

  ```
  while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
      $res = $conn->query("SELECT vendorid FROM vendortotalratings WHERE vendorid = " . $row['vendorid']);
      if($res->num_rows){
          // Update the existing row
          $conn->query("UPDATE vendortotalratings SET totalratings = ".$row['totalratings'].", totalno = ".$row['totalno']." WHERE vendorid = ".$row['vendorid']);
          echo "Affected rows: " . $conn->affected_rows . '<br />';
      }else{
          // Insert a new row
          $res = $conn->query("INSERT INTO vendortotalratings VALUES(".$row['vendorid'].", ".$row['totalratings'].",".$row['totalno'].")");
          if($res) echo "New row inserted <br />";
      }
  }
  ```

So **the complete code** of `try-catch` block would be like this:

```
// your code

try{
    //Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "XXXXXXXX_XXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT vendorid, SUM(ratings) as totalratings, COUNT(userid) as totalno FROM vendorratings GROUP BY vendorid");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

        $res = $conn->query("SELECT vendorid FROM vendortotalratings WHERE vendorid = " . $row['vendorid']);
        if($res->num_rows){
            // Update the existing row
            $conn->query("UPDATE vendortotalratings SET totalratings = ".$row['totalratings'].", totalno = ".$row['totalno']." WHERE vendorid = ".$row['vendorid']);
            echo "Affected rows: " . $conn->affected_rows . '<br />';
        }else{
            // Insert a new row
            $res = $conn->query("INSERT INTO vendortotalratings VALUES(".$row['vendorid'].", ".$row['totalratings'].",".$row['totalno'].")");
            if($res) echo "New row inserted <br />";
        }
    }
}catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out =  json_encode(array("result"=>0));
    echo $json_out; 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but better, it is working now, thank you so much for replying!

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't clarify how the records are first inserted in `vendortotalratings` table. So, assuming that there is already a record in this table for each vendor, you don't have to write a whole new loop.

**Updating `vendortotalratings`:** 
SQL can take care of calculating the total ratings and their counts in a single query which can then replace the loop that you have.

```
UPDATE vendortotalratings vtr
       INNER JOIN 
       (    
         SELECT vendorid, SUM(ratings) AS sumratings, COUNT(ratings) AS countratings 
                FROM vendoratings 
         GROUP BY vendorid
       ) vr
    ON  vtr.vendorid    =   vr.vendorid
    SET 
       vtr.totalratings =   vtr.totalratings + vr.sumratings
      ,vtr.totalno      =   vtr.totalno      + vr.countratings
```

**Computing averages:**  
As for your second question, to compute the average, you could run the following query which will give you the run-time result:

```
SELECT vendorid, totalratings, totalno, 
       CAST((totalratings/totalno) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS avgrating 
FROM vendortotalratings;
```

The variable `avgrating` can be accessed directly in PHP by using `$row['avgrating']` if you're fetching an associative array from the results, or by using the appropriate index number, which in this case should be `$row[3]`